# Isolate Scope in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" ng-app="myapp">
    Parent Scope  {{X}}
    <br />

    <div my-customer>
        <div ng-init="X ='Hello World'">
            ISOLATED SCOPE    {{X}}
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Directive

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
.directive('myCustomer',function()
{
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {}

}
```

})

In above code , I have created custom directive with an isolated scope.
Variable X is initiated  to 'Hello World' in the Isolated scope of the custom directive.But I am getting below Output

```
Parent Scope Hello World 
ISOLATED SCOPE Hello World
```

First {{X}} should be empty ( since custom directive has isolated scope)
but it has the same value as the second {{X}} .
Any idea why?
Angularjs version is
     AngularJS v1.5.3

Comment: I think scope is the concept of angularjs  but not  html. the location of variable in html  does not determine the scope of variable.  in your html if you define `X` under `ng-app`, it will be 'Heollo World`  no matter where you place it

Comment: But when i set scope to true , it behave as expected.
Parent Scope 
ISOLATED SCOPE Hello World

Comment: @harmoniemand answer has the right idea. I don't think it solves it the way you want to, but he's right in suggesting that the scope is not applied. For directives you tend to use templates rather than nesting the DOM. Try using `<script type="text/ng-template" id="mytemplate">` and reference the id as `templateUrl` on the directive. OR hardcode the template in to the `template` property. OR the more complex answer would be to use ng-transclude which strips the contents out, and puts it back with a scope that inherits from the directive.

Answer (score 0):

My first hunch is directive priority. From [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-priority-):

> priority
>
> When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element, sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives before their compile functions get called. Priority is defined as a number. Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first. Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link functions are run in reverse order. The order of directives with the same priority is undefined. The default priority is 0.

and [ng-init has a priority of 450](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit). So it would seem ng-init is being run *before* your scope is isolated by the directive. Try adding 'priority: 451' to your directive declaration.

Comment: changed priority to 451. Same Result.

Answer (score 0):

The scope does simply not get applied at this point.

You have to use the template option.

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.foobar = "foobar";
  }])
  .directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
       foobar: '@'
      },
      template:"INNER SCOPE {{foobar}}",
      controller: function($scope) {
       $scope.foobar = "hello world";
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server" ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Parent Scope {{foobar}}
  <br />

  <div my-customer foobar="Hallo welt" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the culprit of your problem is ng-init usage. In its documentation doesn't recommend their usage in this [way](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

NgInit works with the scope in pre-link stage with high priority and sets the value into the scope.